# Recycler view not showing complete

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycler view showing a list of trips. Each trip has different attributes (from, to, time, etc). But the height of the recycler is fixed and not wrapping to content, so when content is longer, it doesn't shows all fields (or it cuts text).

In the main view, I have this code for inserting the recycler:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/waybill_trips"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And this is the recycler view:
https://pastecode.xyz/view/1a849156

I tried to change the layout_height of several LinearLayouts but coudn't find the right solution. What Im doing wrong?

Comment: When you set the recyclerview's "layout_height" to "wrap_content", it will be the same size as all your items in total - therefore you won't be able to scroll, and the last visible item might seem like it cuts of text... either set it to a height of match_parent (as long as your parent is not wrap_content too). Hope it helps :)

Comment: @MathiasKirkegaard tried with all the layouts and couldn't do it. I know it could be some small thing to fix. Hope to find it soon!